# Can anyone explain about the SQL Range and List Partitions with an example

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

Can anybody explain about the SQL Range and List partitions with an example? i have very much confused about it by studying whitepapers?

Comment: If you are using GUI tools to deal with table partitioning in SQL server 2008,then this post may be useful,rest all I'm studying or revising to present it better. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2009/01/18/easy-table-partitions-with-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i am using scripts to create partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List partition is used when you have a finite list of constants: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. And you want to divide them to 3 partitions: {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10}.
Range is used for infinite lists: { all_values < 10}, { all_values < 20}, { all_values < 100}, { all_values < MaxValue}. If all_values in (1...~)

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple.
Range partitions accepts all the rows where the partition key falls within a specific range, for example all the events with dates between 1980-01-01 and 1990-01-01 falls to partition Eighties - its a range partitioning

If the partition specified for acception of only specific values, such as

```
1980-01-01 00:00:00, 
1981-01-01 00:00:00, 
1982-01-01 00:00:00,
...
1989-01-01 00:00:00
```

(10 specific values)

the rows with this values falls into partition "Eighties' NewYearMidnights" - this is a list partitioning.